# GPS updates aren't called

Tags: android, gps

I want to receive updates from GPS, but i can't. Method onLocationChanged isn't calling. In this application i using Google Maps API, too. I don't know, maybe it is some cause of my problems.

It's code about GPS in MainActivity:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
            {
                      txtLat.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf((int)(location.getLatitude()))  + ","
                              + String.valueOf(((location.getLatitude() * 100) % 100)) + " degrees");

                    txtLong.setText("Longtitude: " + String.valueOf((int)(location.getLongitude()))  + ","
                              + String.valueOf(((location.getLongitude() * 100) % 100)) + " degrees");

            }
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
          };

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

and in Manifest i have declared these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

and other that Google Maps API v2 required

EDIT:
LogCat:

```
06-27 14:25:28.785: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 8% free 2500K/2716K, paused 42ms, total 48ms
06-27 14:25:28.836: I/dalvikvm-heap(5206): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.147MB for 3712016-byte allocation
06-27 14:25:28.906: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 6122K/6344K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
06-27 14:25:28.965: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6122K/6344K, paused 8ms+5ms, total 66ms
06-27 14:25:29.595: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3766K, 53% free 3523K/7464K, paused 24ms+46ms, total 149ms
06-27 14:25:30.025: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_CONCURRENT freed 243K, 51% free 3681K/7464K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 52ms
06-27 14:25:30.045: E/Google Maps Android API(5206): Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
06-27 14:25:30.385: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 146K, 49% free 3826K/7464K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
06-27 14:25:30.685: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_CONCURRENT freed 82K, 44% free 4234K/7464K, paused 16ms+26ms, total 133ms
06-27 14:25:31.066: D/libEGL(5206): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
06-27 14:25:31.095: I/Choreographer(5206): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-27 14:25:31.115: D/libEGL(5206): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-27 14:25:31.175: D/gralloc_goldfish(5206): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-27 14:25:31.819: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_CONCURRENT freed 402K, 41% free 4428K/7464K, paused 30ms+60ms, total 386ms
06-27 14:25:31.915: D/dalvikvm(5206): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 428ms
06-27 14:25:32.427: D/dalvikvm(5206): GC_CONCURRENT freed 630K, 41% free 4429K/7464K, paused 31ms+18ms, total 100ms
06-27 14:25:32.427: D/dalvikvm(5206): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 59ms
06-27 14:33:03.695: E/Trace(5381): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-27 14:33:04.395: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 46K, 9% free 2500K/2720K, paused 42ms, total 45ms
06-27 14:33:04.435: I/dalvikvm-heap(5381): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.147MB for 3712016-byte allocation
06-27 14:33:04.485: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 6122K/6348K, paused 43ms, total 44ms
06-27 14:33:04.555: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6122K/6348K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 70ms
06-27 14:33:05.235: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3774K, 53% free 3500K/7448K, paused 20ms+84ms, total 157ms
06-27 14:33:05.615: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_CONCURRENT freed 232K, 51% free 3663K/7448K, paused 72ms+5ms, total 118ms
06-27 14:33:05.645: E/Google Maps Android API(5381): Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above
06-27 14:33:05.875: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 190K, 49% free 3847K/7448K, paused 39ms, total 40ms
06-27 14:33:06.268: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_CONCURRENT freed 62K, 44% free 4223K/7448K, paused 71ms+77ms, total 284ms
06-27 14:33:06.815: D/libEGL(5381): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
06-27 14:33:06.865: D/libEGL(5381): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
06-27 14:33:06.906: I/Choreographer(5381): Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-27 14:33:07.005: D/gralloc_goldfish(5381): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-27 14:33:07.455: I/Choreographer(5381): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-27 14:33:07.545: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_CONCURRENT freed 381K, 41% free 4427K/7448K, paused 8ms+111ms, total 349ms
06-27 14:33:07.545: D/dalvikvm(5381): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 237ms
06-27 14:33:08.246: D/dalvikvm(5381): GC_CONCURRENT freed 630K, 41% free 4430K/7448K, paused 72ms+7ms, total 171ms
06-27 14:33:08.246: D/dalvikvm(5381): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
```

Comment: put logs in the callbacks, does they get called?

Comment: Are you outside when doing this? Do you see a steady GPS Signal instead of a blinking one?

Comment: have you waited enough? The GPS needs some time especially if you are inside

Comment: I'm inside flat. I see blinking GPS signal and i think i have waited enought (at least 5 minutes)

Comment: Does your device's GPS is on ?

Comment: he sees it blinking so it's probably on :)

Comment: Yes of course i enabled GPS on my device :) I added logs in main post.

Comment: if you're inside, how do you expect your GPS to work ? It will do nothing except consume battery.

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to retrieve the location using the GPS provider, and you're inside a building or have lousy GPS reception, the onLocationChanged will never be called.

There will be no automatic fallback to Wifi or celltower.

Always check what kind of provider you are using, even when specifying criteria.

Google has released a bunch of [new Location APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) through Google Play Services that offers more efficient ways of retrieving user location (improving accuracy and battery-life).

I suggest you take a look at those and follow the [Retrieving the Current Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) tutorial (it includes a sample app that you can download).